why are allowSquashMerge and allowAutoMerge always null in octokit?
I am working with a large number of repositories - and building some tools to make sure everything is in sync - I have the following code:
  var repository = await client.Repository.Get(Owner, repo);
        var branchProtection = await client.Repository.Branch.GetBranchProtection(Owner, repo, "master");
        

        var allTeams = await client.Repository.GetAllTeams(Owner, repo);
        var theTeam = allTeams.FirstOrDefault( x=>x.Name=="Whatever");
        var flagsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>
        {
            { "IsTravelMember", theTeam != null},
            { "IsTravelAdmin", theTeam?.Permission == "admin"},
            { "AllowSquashMerging", repository.AllowSquashMerge ?? false },
            { "AllowAutoMerge", repository.AllowAutoMerge ?? false },
            { "AutomaticallyDeleteHeadBranches", repository.DeleteBranchOnMerge ?? false },
            { "MasterBranchRequireLinearHistory", branchProtection.RequiredLinearHistory.Enabled },
            { "RequireSignedCommits", branchProtection.RequiredSignatures.Enabled }
        };

but oddly all fields on repository like allowAutoMerge are juswt null all the time.
What am I doing wrong?
